# How do I get the application name of an Android app from the application ID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm making a program and need to convert application IDs like "com.android.chrome" to their application names like "Google Chrome".

Comment: What are you making your program with? Is it a web app (running in web browser)?

Comment: Yes I'm using JS, HTML, CSS, and PHP

Comment: then you can fetch google play store page of the app you want (`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your app id here>`), and parse the app name out of the page

Comment: OK I'll try this thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this repo: https://github.com/petarov/google-android-app-ids

Or use directly its JSON file [`dist/google-app-ids.json`](https://github.com/petarov/google-android-app-ids/blob/master/dist/google-app-ids.json). It's far from complete, but it works for most native and popular android apps.